# Laptop Backlight goes off repeatedly

Tags: performance

I have a SONY Vaio laptop - VPCEA24FM. The problem is the backlight goes off for around 2-3 seconds, whenever i try to move my screen a little bit. This problem started yesterday night only.If i adjust the screen, the power goes for sometime and again comes back.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a hardware problem, most likely the cable that powers the backlight, though possibly the inverter board if it's a cold-cathode backlight.

Contact Sony for repair and service.